# X11Forwarding using SSH and Netcat

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, x11-forwarding, netcat

From my machine, I must connect through nodes `A`, `B`, and `C`, to reach `target`:

```
localhost -> A -> B -> C -> target
```

Machine  `A` is configured to refuse `X11 Forwarding`, so I guess I shouldn't be able to open graphical interfaces via connections passing through `ssh A`.

However, setting up `~/.ssh/config` file, and adding `ProxyCommand`'s using `netcat`, I've been able to open a graphical application at `target`, simply executing `ssh -XY target`. The setup in `~/.ssh/config` goes as follows:

```
Host A
    Hostname domainA
Host B
    Hostname domainB
    ProxyCommand ssh A nc %h %p
Host C
    Hostname domainC
    ProxyCommand ssh B nc %h %p
Host target
    Hostname domain-target
    ProxyCommand ssh C nc %h %p
```

The connection itself is working, and I'm very fine with that. Happens, though, I did not actually understand what is going on behind the curtains.

When I run `ssh -XY target`, what actually happens, and why is it I'm able to open GUI via this *tunnel*, even though host `A` does not allow `X11 Forwarding`?

---

I understand it's nice to show some effort, so here goes the farther I've been able to get, trying to understand the execution above. I have replaced `target` with `TARGET`, and host `C` with `HOST_C`.

```
$ ssh -vXY TARGET
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/rubens/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/rubens/.ssh/config line 20: Applying options for TARGET
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh HOST_C nc TARGET 22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/rubens/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/rubens/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0,
    remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA (some numbers...)
debug1: Host 'TARGET' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/rubens/.ssh/known_hosts:51
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/rubens/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to TARGET (via proxy).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-48-generic x86_64)
...
rubens@TARGET:~
$ # prompt, and I'm able to open graphical apps, like gkrellm
```

The connection seems to take place first with host `C`, that needs previous connections to take place (backward recursion stacking dependencies, and solving them in LIFO order).

At host `A`, which is the first level of connection, is the `X11Forward` permission applied? Or does it simply creates a tunnel of `nc` connections, until machine `target`, and returns an open socket I later use into something like:

```
ssh -XY (open socket resulting from connections A->B->C->target)
```

If so, is it fine I'm able to connect with `X11Forwarding`? Or maybe there is something wrong with host `A`'s setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host A does not forward X11 connections, host C does. You connect to host C and open an X11 application (client) that is then displayed on your local machine (server). The connection is passed through intermediate nodes A and B, but this is unrelated to the X forwarding which is set up between your local host and host C.

Note: You don't need netcat, since you use OpenSSH which has the `-W` option for that purpose.

Comment: +1 `-W %h:%p` instead of `nc %h %p` works just fine. Yet, I haven't got exactly what happens when I connect using `ssh -XY target`. Is the connection opened through the intermediate nodes, and a socket port is returned, to which I actually `ssh (socket)`? Or do the connections to hosts `A`, `B`, and `C`, before connecting to `target`, just perform authentications, without actually being part of the stack of packet exchanging (packet goes from `localhost` -> `A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `target`, or, after authentication, just `localhost` -> `target`)?

Comment: The packets are passed through each intermediate node.